# Error 500 al ejecutar microservicio en springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

Trabajo con springboot creando microservicios. Tengo mi código sin ningún error, compilo y no marca ningún error; subo mi .war a WebLogic y despliega, pero al momento de checar el microservicio en postman me marca el error

> "status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"

Tal vez mi código no esté bien estructurado y ese sea el motivo. Adjunto mis clases de mi proyecto.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EstatusController {
@Autowired
private IEstatusServices estatusServicesImpl;
@GetMapping(path = "/estatus")
public ResponseEntity<?> findAll() {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<EstatusDto> listCat = null;

    try {
        listCat = estatusServicesImpl.findAll();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        response.put("mensaje",ConstantesUtil.MESSAGE_ERROR_CONSULTA);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, 
 HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    if (listCat == null) {
        response.put("mensaje", "");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<EstatusDto>>(listCat, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping(path = "estatus/activo/{IdActivo}")
public ResponseEntity<?> findByIdActivo(@PathVariable("idActivo") int idActivo) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<EstatusDto> listCat = null;

    try {
        listCat = estatusServicesImpl.findbyidActivo(idActivo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.put("mensaje",ConstantesUtil.MESSAGE_ERROR_CONSULTA);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    if (listCat == null) {
        response.put("mensaje", "");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<EstatusDto>>(listCat, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

DAO

```
public interface IActivoDao  extends CrudRepository<ActivoModel,String> {
List<EstatusDto> findByidActivo(int idActivo);
 }
```

DTO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EstatusDto implements Serializable {
/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Setter
@Getter
private int idActivo;
@Setter
@Getter
private String activo;

}
```

model

```
 @Entity
@Table (name="ACTIVO")
public class ActivoModel implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column (name="IDACTIVO")
@Setter@Getter
private int idActivo;
@Column (name="ACTIVO")
@Setter@Getter
private String activo;
@Column (name="FECHAREGISTRO")
@Setter@Getter
private Date fechaRegistro;
@Column (name="IDUSUARIOREGISTRO")
@Setter@Getter
private int idUsuarioRegistro;
}
```

mi service

```
 @Service
 public interface IEstatusServices {
    List<EstatusDto> findAll();
List<EstatusDto> findbyidActivo(int idActivo);
}
```

mi serviceimplement

```
  @Service("estatusServicesImpl")
  public class EstatusServicesImpl implements IEstatusServices {
  @Autowired
  private IActivoDao activoDaoImpl;

@Autowired
private Mapper dozerMapper;

@Override
public List<EstatusDto> findAll() {
    List<EstatusDto> list = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("ingres a sevicicio estatus");
        List<ActivoModel> list2 = (List<ActivoModel>) activoDaoImpl.findAll();

        System.out.println("dro" + dozerMapper);
        if (list2 != null && list2.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("ingreso if");

            list = list2.stream().map((catalogo) -> {
                return dozerMapper.map(catalogo, EstatusDto.class);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

@Override
public List<EstatusDto> findbyidActivo(int idActivo) {
    
    List<EstatusDto> listDto = null;
    List<EstatusDto> listModel = activoDaoImpl.findByidActivo( idActivo);
    if (listModel != null) {
        listDto = listModel.stream().map((catalogo) -> {
            return dozerMapper.map(catalogo, EstatusDto.class);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    return listDto;
}
}
```

Este el error me manda cuando lo ejecuto con potsman en la consola de eclipse

```
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class mx.gob.issfam.dti.api.dto.EstatusDto and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Intente agregar la siguiente línea a su archivo application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```